# PHP if statement for anchor tag is not working

Tags: php, html, session

If statements for anchor tag is not working. Inside the condition I've checked, if session has a value, then goes to dashboard.But if session has no value,then goes to sign up page.

I checked this code after login, so $_SESSION['c_id'] is set.And so $_SESSION['c_id'] has a value and is not empty and should show the dashboard option. But the navigation bar showing the sign up option even though the session is not empty which refers that the else condition is working here.

I tried this following PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
I am not sure if my code is right or wrong or have syntax error or logical error.

```
    <li><a href="order_page.php">Order Anything</a></li>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['c_id'])):?>
        <li><a href="index2.php"> Dashboard</a> </li>

    <?php elseif(isset($_SESSION['p_id'])):?>
        <li><a href="index1.php"> Dashboard</a></li>

    <?php else:?>
        <li><a href="BeProvider.htm">Sign up</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <li><a href="contact.htm">  Help Center</a></li>
```

Comment: enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php then tell us what the error is, if any.

Comment: Do you `start_session()` anywhere in this script?

Comment: just to extend @FunkFortyNiner comment, add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script

Comment: If you aim to redirect the user after checking the session, then you should use `header('location: mypage.php')` instead of an anchor tag.

Comment: @timarcosdias I'm pretty sure this is more like access-level vieawable links - not an attempt at a redirect using anchor tags

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I see. I was just wondering why he said "then goes to dashboard". Maybe he needs a redirect.

Comment: one has to wonder where the OP is in all this. The question is missing detail.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to include <server.php> attempting to access session without starting any session. I'm new kid on this block. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

you need session_start() to use Session on your page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<li><a href="order_page.php">Order Anything</a></li>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['c_id'])):?>
        <li><a href="index2.php"> Dashboard</a> </li>

    <?php elseif(isset($_SESSION['p_id'])):?>
        <li><a href="index1.php"> Dashboard</a></li>

    <?php else:?>
        <li><a href="BeProvider.htm">Sign up</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <li><a href="contact.htm">  Help Center</a></li>
```

read this manual [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: you should add an explanation - OP won't understand the solution and better future code, they'll merely remember it, causing them to be constantly looking up code.